# Foreground notification not trigger in react native. How to implement notification

Tags: reactjs, react-native

If you're using rnfirebase for notifications in your React Native app and the notifications are not showing when the app is in the foreground, you might need to configure the notification behavior for foreground notifications.

Make sure you have configured the notification channels correctly and that your notifications are being sent with the appropriate priority settings. Additionally, ensure that your app's notification handling code is properly implemented to display notifications in the foreground.

For more detailed information and best practices, refer to the official documentation for rnfirebase at https://rnfirebase.io. This documentation provides detailed guides and examples for setting up and using notifications with rnfirebase.

Answer (score 0):

As per [rnfirebase doc](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#message-handlers), notification banner is not showing in foreground.
You can use [notifee](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/integrations/fcm) to show foreground banner.

Reference Code:

**App.ts**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(onMessageReceived);
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

const onMessageReceived = (
  message: FirebaseMessagingTypes.RemoteMessage,
) => {
  const {title, body, ios} = message.notification;

  const notification: Notification = {
    title: title,
    subtitle: ios?.subtitle,
    body: body,
    data: message.data,
  };
  notifee.displayNotification(notification);
}
```